# how would I combine these two queries?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my existing query:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT s.*, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) AS `date`, 
f.userid as favoritehash FROM songs s 
LEFT JOIN favorites f ON f.favorite = s.id AND f.userid = '$userhash' 
ORDER BY s.date DESC");
```

It gathers all my songs and the associated `favorite` information from my db.

This is a basic pagination query that returns values from my db by groups of days:

```
$query = mysql_query("
        select * from songs t1 join (
        select to_days(date) day from songs 
        group by day 
        order by day desc 
        limit $start_row, $items_per_page
        ) t2
        on to_days(t1.date) = t2.day
        order by day desc") or die(mysql_error());
```

Here is the column info for the two tables `songs` and `favorites`

Songs: [image: songs schema]

Favorites: [image: favorites schema]

The correlation between favorites and songs is pretty simple where the `favorite` value in `favorites` holds the unique `id` of the song it is a favorite of.

My question is how would I combine these two queries so as to return all the information in the original query but grouped and paginated as it is in the second query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MySQL and not familiar with using the "limit", but this script might work. The LEFT JOIN with favorites should not increase the row count and append the columns. Would the "limit" work on the outer script also?

```
select s.*,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) AS `date`, f.userid as favoritehash  
from   songs s 
       join (
              select to_days(date) day 
              from songs 
              group by to_days(date) 
              order by day desc
              limit $start_row, $items_per_page
             ) s2  on to_days(s.date) = s2.day
    LEFT JOIN favorites f ON f.favorite = s.id AND f.userid = '$userhash'
```

Comment: I will give that a try. `limit` in this usage tells the query what row to start on and how many times to return.  It limits how many rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.* 
FROM favorites as A
JOIN ( 
    select * from songs t1 join (
        select to_days(date) day from songs 
        group by day 
        order by day desc 
        limit $start_row, $items_per_page
        ) t2
        on to_days(t1.date) = t2.day
        order by day desc
) as B
ON A.Favorite = B.ID
ORDER BY B.DAY, B.ID
```

Comment: was getting: `Unknown column 'b.ID' in 'on clause` but changed the `b` to `B` and it works however grouping/sorting does not work. It returns 20 rows when I limit to 10 starting `Wed Dec 31st`

Comment: It seems to be.. grouping or ordering by the favorite count rather than the days and songs? Screenshot: http://cl.ly/0y3P020y363O0t1d3004